# How to change a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I pulled an image I found on docker hub, I made some changes and it is working locally.

But now need to push it to docker hub. I used the following guide https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/ and I was able to push the image on my repository.

The problem is that the changes I made are not in the image I just pushed. I think the reason is because I didn’t build (after making the changes) from the docker file. But given that the image I modified is not mine I don’t know where can I find(if I can ?) the DOCKERFILE, build the image and then push it.

Thank you

Comment: Try to commit a running container by `docker commit` and then, push the generated image.

Comment: "I made some changes" This needs more explanation and clarification.

Comment: You can (and should!) write your own Dockerfile that starts FROM the public image and RUNs some commands to adjust it to taste; when you `docker build` it will create the new image for you, and you'll have a record of what you did that you can share with your colleagues to help them build the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to commit the changes that you made to the docker image using docker commit command. Otherwise you will lose them once the container is destroyed in which you made the changes.

Also you can push the new image to Docker hub and later on pull the new image and find your changes in place.

Command: `docker commit CONTAINER_ID IMAGE_NAME`